# How to calculate a FedEx Smartpost tracking number' check digit

Tags: fedex, check-digit

FedEx Ground's tracking numbers have different digits: 12, 15, 20, 22.

12-digits tracking numbers use mod 11 algorithm. 
Others use mod 10 algorithm.

But recently I got some 20-digits FedEx Smartpost tracking numbers which can't identified by both algorithms.

So, how can I identify these tracking numbers?

Sample tracking numbers:
7489999873402038xxxx
6129270107532465xxxx

---

I figured this out.

see:
http://images.fedex.com/us/software/pdf/FedEx_SmartPost_Job_Aid_v2600_06222012.pdf
https://www.pdffiller.com/en/project/10655396.htm

22 digits tracking numbers remove 2 digits application identifiers (91 or 92).
We need add application identifiers to the tracking numbers before mod 10 algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 20 digit codes need either 91 (old) or 92 (new) before the code. Pre-pend those and apply a standard mod-10 algorithm used by the IMpb standard.

Comment: The 20-digits tracking numbers I mentioned are neither stared with 91 nor 92. But I can track them via Fedex website.

Comment: This answer is correct. I misunderstanding this answer before.